# Cannot assert against object

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop, object

This is probably a very simple Object Oriented Programming question. What I am trying to do is take 2 empty objects, use a query to pull data from a database, populate the empty objects with the data returned from the query, and then assert against them. See the code below:

```
        object test1;
        object test2;

        using (SqlConnection dbconnection = new SqlConnection(expconnstr))
        {
            dbconnection.Open();

            var expcommand = new SqlCommand(expectedquery, dbconnection);
            var actcommand = new SqlCommand(actualquery, dbconnection);

            using (SqlDataReader expreader = expcommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (expreader.Read())
                {                        
                    test1 = expreader.GetValue(0);
                    expreader.Close();
                }
            }

            using (SqlDataReader actreader = actcommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (actreader.Read())
                {
                    test2 = actreader.GetValue(0);
                    actreader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        Assert.AreSame(test1, test2);
```

I wrote a very similar test method in VB following the same patterns and the VB code executed just fine. However whilst transitioning from VB to C#, I run into issues such as these. The compiler says "Use of unassigned variable" at the assert. However, I thought I was assigning to a value within the code block above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please excuse the variables which are assumed to have values (actreader, expcommand, dbconnection, etc). They are assumed to have values and work fine. It is the assert that is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibility exists that `actreader.Read()` returns false, thus `test2` may never get assigned and the compiler error.

You can remedy the issue by explicitly setting `test1` & `test2` initially to `null`:

```
object test1 = null;
object test2 = null;
```

Comment: Excellent, this fixed the problem! Though I made another mistake along the way.. The assert I used, 'Assert.AreSame' is checking that two objects are the name. What I need to do is check that the data values are the name. Instead, I used 'Assert.AreEqual' and the test works perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value to the variable within the `if` block.  Since **local variables are not initialized with default values**, there is no guarantee that that by the time you get to your `Assert` statement that the variable has been assigned a value.

One or more of the following things are happening:

- `expreader.Read()` is returning `false`
- `actreader.Read()` is returning `false`